# Comparing two lists and based on list1 order need to update order of list2 in poweshell

Tags: powershell

I’m new to power shell, I have 2 lists like

```
$list1=[‘1’,’2’,’5’,’6’,’4’];
$list2=[‘9’,’10’,’8’,’6’,’5’];
$expectedoutputlist=[‘9’,’10’,’8’,’5’,’6’];
```

Based on the order of list1 I need to update the order of list2 where it have common items in both the lists if not remain same.

I need solution in getting desired output in power shell , please help me

Comment: Why does `9` and `10` get to stay at the start of `$list2`, why not move them to the back of the list since they aren't found in `$list1`?

Comment: My requirement is to re-order the $list2 items based $list1 order, where I have common items(Simply in $list1 5 comes first and then 6, but in $list2 6 first and 5 next i need to swap them only)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Array.IndexOf()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof) method.
This works in your case because for items in $list2 that cannot be found in $list1, IndexOf() returns `-1`, so these will be sorted on top.

The way you define your 'lists' is wrong/quite unusual.. The square brackets should not be there.
Below $list1 and $list2 are defined as arrays.

```
$list1 = '1','2','5','6','4'
$list2 = '9','10','8','6','5'

$sorted = $list2 | Sort-Object { $list1.IndexOf($_) }
```

Result:

```
$sorted -join ','  # --> 9,10,8,5,6
```

or if you rather see the values quoted:

```
($sorted | ForEach-Object { "'{0}'" -f $_ }) -join ','  # --> '9','10','8','5','6'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following script could help:

```
$list1 = '1','2','5','6','4'
$list2 = '9','10','8','6','5'

$list1Reduced = $list1.Where({ $_ -in $list2 })

$ii1 = 0
for ( $ii2 = 0; $ii2 -lt $list2.Count; $ii2++ ) {
    if ( $list2[$ii2] -in $list1Reduced ) {
        $list2[$ii2] = $list1Reduced[$ii1]
        $ii1++
        if ( $ii1 -ge $list1Reduced.Count ) { $ii1 = 0 } # or $ii1--
    }
}
$list2 -join ','
```

**Output**: `.\SO\69359305.ps1`

> ```
> 9,10,8,5,6
> ```